# Creating an executable from a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.4 and I wish to convert my .PY file into a single .EXE file.  I have heard of Py2exe, cx_freeze and Pyinstaller.  Are any of these better than the others?

Also, my Python source code calls upon external resources, such as Firefox.  How do you ensure that the functionality of Firefox is included, given that the person I am handing the app to might not even have it installed on their PC?

Comment: To improve your question, I'd tell more about the use case and ask about suitability of the mentioned tools for the task instead of asking for a preference of one over the others. In a separate question, I would describe what's done with the external resources and ask how to best bundle them with your application, or what alternatives (e.g. to using Firefox) might make packaging easier.